# rosjava(android) pubsub tutorial

Tags: roscore, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I build rosjava pubsub tutorial without error. and I can run the PubSubTutorial on the AVD.
It seems working well. but I don't know it is actually publishing the topic.

I ran the roscore in ubuntu PC, but PubSubTutorial is not trying to connect to roscore in PC.
MainActivity Manifest has internet permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Should I run the roscore(rosjava)? the DEFAULT_MASTER_URI is "http://localhost:11311/" was configured by NodeRunner.createDefault() function.

```
[2011-06-23 22:41:19 - MainActivity] Android Launch!
[2011-06-23 22:41:19 - MainActivity] adb is running normally.
[2011-06-23 22:41:19 - MainActivity] Performing org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.MainActivity activity launch
[2011-06-23 22:41:19 - MainActivity] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'scv'
[2011-06-23 22:41:21 - MainActivity] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-06-23 22:41:21 - MainActivity] Starting activity org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-06-23 22:41:22 - MainActivity] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.ros.tutorials.pubsub/.MainActivity }
```

How can I use this tutorial?
Please give me a answer. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10371/rosjava(android)-pubsub-tutorial/) by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-06-23**:
Could you clarify your question? You say that it built and runs fine on the AVD. Your logcat looks fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To connect to a roscore that is running in an AVD, you'll need to use adb forwarding. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports

For example:

adb forward tcp:11311 tcp:11311

That will forward all TCP connections to port 11311 on your host to your AVD on port 11311.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1